# Create a visitor counter at Localhost

Tags: javascript, java, angular, typescript

im currently struggling to create a counter of each visitor(doesnt have to be unique) for Localhost - since it shouldnt be online. Currently i can only use Java / JavaScript /Typescript e.g Angular, Bootstrap etc.

Is there any possibility to integrate a counter without having to use PHP? And how?
Because every attempt to solve it was with PHP or it was just an online counter, not for my Localhost page.

this code Passage i found on Stackoverflow (by Rahul Singh) couldnt solve it.

```
private _pageCount = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
count$ = this._pageCount.asObservable();

incrementPageCount(){
    const pageCount = this.af.object('/pageCount/').$ref
      .ref.transaction(count => {
        return count + 1;
      }).then((data) => {return data.snapshot.node_.value_;});

    return pageCount;
}
```

Comment: _it was just an online counter, not for my Localhost page.._ Do you know what "localhost" is?

Comment: Localhost is only accessible from my Computer and only if i start my Server? Since im just coding for only 3 Months im not very sure.

Comment: _Localhost is only accessible from my Computer and only if i start my Server..._ Exactly!

Comment: the thing is that i still want to track the Visits - even if they are only my own. The best case would be to integrate it in my Database

Edit: Database is via MariaDB / Running with Springboot @ Serverside with Java

Comment: You can still implement your code and track your visitors

Comment: Does it mean that you can only use front end technologies for this? no serverside code?

Comment: i can actually use Serverside Code, but only Java and Frameworks like Springboot. But i actually managed to solve it via a counter on every NgInit/Initialize. So everything is fine now :) Thank you